# Is there way to get table name reference before column names in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables that have many same column names so I need to add the table name before the column names when I join the tables. Is there some way to get table name reference before the column name without need to type it before every column in select clause?

In this example there are many columns in both tables and many of them have same names so I need to write TABLE2. before every column in select. Is there easier way to add it?

```
SELECT TABLE1.column1, TABLE2.column2, TABLE2.column3, TABLE2.column4,...
FROM TABLE1, TABLE2
WHERE TABLE1.column1 = TABLE2.column1;
```

Comment: the only way is setting an alias in each table... `table1 as a, table2 as b ` and using `a.column = b.column`

Comment: Your example has no duplicate column names, so it is not conveying anything useful.

Comment: @Roy Yes, use a table alias; however your code sample is syntactically invalid as Oracle does not use the `AS` keyword before table aliases.

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed

Answer (score 2):

Use table aliases:

```sql
SELECT t1.column1,
       t2.column2,
       t2.column3,
       t2.column4 --, ...
FROM   TABLE1 t1
       INNER JOIN TABLE2 t2
       ON ( t1.column1 = t2.column1 );
```

(And use ANSI join syntax rather than the legacy Oracle comma join syntax as it makes the relationships much clearer)